# How to convert decimal number to degrees using calculator (pls read the details)?

Tags: calculator

For example if I have tan30 and I type it in the calculator to get 0,577350269 is there a way to revert that number with the calculator to get 30 degrees?
Another example of the same type if I wanna get tanß = cosα / (2 - sinα) and the α = 30 degrees, so it is = 0,577350269 is there a way to revert it with the calculator to degrees so the ß would be 30 degrees insted of 0,577350269?

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear, but i think you're looking for $\tan^{-1}$ button on your calculator.

Comment: Can you please write with standard english words instead of "pls" and "wanna"? It will be easier to read by members of this international community.

Comment: The inverse trigonometric functions ($\arcsin,\arccos,\arctan$) are often obtained by prefixing with the INV key. The angle is returned in the current angular mode.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang and also by native English speakers.

Comment: @AlgTop Thank you I am glad that you understood me and helped me! :)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I am from Europe and when I can I write as short as I can, at least it isn't in Chinese and please don't judge me if you don't wanna help me, I'll write it how I want!

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for your comment also. :)

Comment: And I will downvote questioners who flaunt community norms.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang You should get a life.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, but my life is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your calculator, yes!
Most calculators that have the sin, cos, tan functions also come with sin^(-1), cos^(-1) and tan^(-1) functions!

If tan(30)=0.577, then tan^(-1)(0.577)=30  (if you want this result in DEGREES instead of RADIANS, make sure you change the settings on your calculator (it's different for every calculator).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! AlgTop also helped me, but he didn't give an answer, just a comment. Thank you for your wide explanation. :)